# EditorFor isn't working on classes in different dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, editorfor

I have a solution with two projects.

One of them contains data access layer classes (DAL.dll), and the other one is an ASP.NET MVC project. The ASP.NET MVC project depends on DAL.dll.
I want to use the DAL.dll classes in a model class in the ASP.NET MVC project.

Suppose that I have a class in DAL.dll as follows:

```
public class Test{

  public string Description{get;set;}

}
```

And, in the ASP.NET MVC project I have a model class that uses Test.cs as follows:

```
public class ModelClass{

  Test CrudModel{get;set;}

  public string Description{get;set;} 

}
```

And, in my view (*.cshtml) I have following code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CrudModel.Description, "tinymce_jquery_min")
```

In the above code, `@Html.EditorFor` does not render "tinymce_jquery_min" template.

But, when I use the following code, `@Html.EditorFor` does render "tinymce_jquery_min" template:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, "tinymce_jquery_min")
```

Why @Html.EditorFor only renders template for properties those are in model class in the ASP.NET MVC project and not for properties in a different dll?

## Updated

"tinymce_jquery_min" template is as follow :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")"      type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(loadTinyMCE, 500);
    });

  function loadTinyMCE() {
      $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({


              script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
              theme: "advanced",

              height: "300",
              width: "400",
              verify_html: false,

              theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                      theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
              theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
              theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
              theme_advanced_resizing: false,


              convert_urls: false,


              template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
              external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
              external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
              media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js"

          });
  }





 </script>
        @Html.TextArea(string.Empty,  
          ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue  
       )
```

Comment: Where is your "tinymce_jquery_min" partial view?

Comment: [ataravati](http://stackoverflow.com/users/781366/ataravati) ,i updated the post with "tinymce_jquery_min" template.

Comment: No, I didn't want to see the code. Where is the template located, in which folder?

Comment: But, anyway, why isn't your partial view strongly-typed?

Comment: Excuse me,i do not understand your question.My template is located in "Views/Shared/EditorTemplates".And would you please guide me how my template can be strongly-typed?I am newbie in ASP MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [ataravati](http://www.example.com/)  for your help.
It seems there is a bug in my template.
I must change

```
   ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName
```

to

```
   ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId
```

Because ASP MVC creates different value for id property and name property in following code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CrudModel.Description, "tinymce_jquery_min")
```

then

```
  ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make your partial view strongly-typed. Define the model (which is of type string in this case), and use `Html.TextAreaFor` to render your TextArea:

```
@model string

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(loadTinyMCE, 500);
   });

   function loadTinyMCE() {
      $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({


              script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
              theme: "advanced",

              height: "300",
              width: "400",
              verify_html: false,

              theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                      theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
              theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
              theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
              theme_advanced_resizing: false,


              convert_urls: false,


              template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
              external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
              external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
              media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js"

      });
   }
</script>

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model)
```